# Uploading images to firebaseStorage

Tags: swift

I have been building an app during the past month where you can upload your favorite memories. Each memory has a photo, date, short description, and place where it developed.

**So the user was able to add memories, I did the following function for the photo part:**

```
private func agregarRecuerdoFirebase() {
    guard let imagenSeleccionada = self.imagen else {
        print("No hay imagen")
        return
    }
    
    guard let imagenData = imagenSeleccionada.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
        return
    }
    
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://chinahub-68043.appspot.com")
    let storageRecuerdos = storageRef.child("recuerdos").child("recuerdoss")
    
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/png"
    storageRecuerdos.putData(imagenData, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetaData, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
```

**Everything is working fine except the uploading to Firebase Storage. After uploading one photo to the storage, when I want to upload a second one it won't let me. Instead, the second image will replace the first one.** **How could I create a unique ID every time I want to add a new memory so that I could store it under that ID into the Storage??** **Or is there another way for being able to achieve what I want??**

Comment: That's because you are sending a data set to exactly the same child named 'recuerdos' over and over.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace below line in your project

```
let storageRecuerdos = storageRef.child("recuerdos").child("recuerdoss\(UUID().uuidString)\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
```